# New PC Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, noise

I have just bought a new power supply for my PC.

Can I plug it in and start it up without inserting into my PC?

I want to see how loud it is.

Will it blow up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not [power the PSU without load](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/power/sup/outputLoading-c.html).

> A power supply that is turned on with no load attached will either fail to function or will function improperly... Better-quality supplies will detect a no-load situation and shut down.
>
> The amount of load required by a particular power supply is often specified as its minimum load... You will sometimes see these minimum current requirements listed as part of the power supply's [output specifications](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/power/sup/spec_Output.htm).
>
> Modern power supplies have drastically reduced the degree to which loading is an issue. Most newer power supplies have very small +3.3 V and +5 V load requirements, and many have no minimum at all for +12 V. The lower loading requirements make testing and troubleshooting much easier.

PSUs are supposed to be either connected with your system or loaded with special devices for testing. I would suggest that you connect the Unit to your system and then check the sound.

Answer (score 2):

It's not advised to plug a powersupply in without a load. You should either plug it into a motherboard or a psu tester.  Some advanced psu will simply not power on without a load but in many cases the psu without load will fail (and in some cases perminant damage).

Comment: Depending on the psu you could probably get away with connecting an old optical drive or hard drive.

Comment: Yup, it all depends on what the load requirements are of the psu model.  As a common practice when I'm testing a psu I have a 1' AT extension so I'll pop that on and then use an old AT motherboard to see if it gives me the missing RAM beeps.